# Rails 2.3.2 - content_type "application/pdf" Issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, pdf

I am using Rails 2.3.2. Sending mail function, I want to open that PDF file. Here is code that I have used:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome_email(user)
    recipients    user.email
    from          "test@gmail.com"
    subject       "Test Mail"
    sent_on       Time.now
    body          "Welcome to Our System"
    content_type  "application/pdf"

  end
end
```

And this file getting name for "noname" and can't open.

How Solve this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- In this action mailer guid guide: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html, It says to make view file into app/views/[action_mailer_model_name]/[method_name]
- There is no need to pass explicitly file 'application/pdf' in mail function ,Action Mailer so smart that it identify content-type automatically while reading file.

Hopefully I help you!

Comment: if i add                                                                                      
attachments['test.pdf'] = File.read("app/views/user_mailer/welcome_email")    getting an error;                                                                                       undefined local variable or method `attachments' for #<UserMailer:0x77a7cf8>